# I have list that I need 2 columns (Choice) to pull up different fields

Tags: list, custom-list, custom-form, custom

I have a column named Origination and a column named Sub organization.

When the user choose choice A in organization I need specific choices to pop up for Sub Organization.
When the user chooses Choice B in organization I need different choices to pop up in Sub organization.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for **Cascading Lookup**.

There are several of these, like the one on [CodePlex](http://spcd.codeplex.com), and Mark D have made support for it in his [SPServices (SPCascadeDropdowns)](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns).

**Update**:
If you want a very quick and dirty solution you could do this:
By using SPFieldChoice and prefixing the values with previous values like this:

- Choice Country

  - Norway
  - Sweden
  - Denmark
- Choice City

  - Norway - Oslo
  - Norway - Ålesund
  - Sweden - Stockholm

You can use jQuery to filter them like this:

```
var $fields = $('.ms-formbody').filter(function() {
  return $(this).html().match(/spfieldchoice/i);
});
var $s = $fields.last().find('select');
  $s.find('option').each(function() {
  var $o = $(this);
  $o.text($o.text().replace(/.* - /, ''));
});
var $c = $s.find('option').clone();
$fields.first().find('select').change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $s.empty().append($c);
  $s.find('option').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val().indexOf(val) < 0;
  }).remove();
}).change();​
```

Comment: My issue becomes that I do not have access to SharePoint Designer or InfoPath. I really just have the basics to use.

Comment: You could find one that is sandboxed solution, in that case you could just upload it. To be honest we have such solution at work, a sandboxed solution for cascading fields that use the "RelatedField" property for mapping. But I'm afraid it's closed source :(