# Pro grammatically adding choice field with another field relation

Tags: 2010, list, development, lookup-column, column

sorry about the title am not sure how i should name it.

I want to be able to create two columns for a list that have a division - subdivision relation.

If in the first field if i choose People the second field lists people, if i choose Animals in the first field the second one gives me a list of animals.

How can i achieve this ? It has to be in C#.

Thanks alot ;)

Comment: So it has to be _C#_ and can not be in JavaScript at all? If you could use JavaScript then this could perhaps help: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45912/i-have-list-that-i-need-2-columns-choice-to-pull-up-different-fields/45913#45913

Comment: I think the first thing he gives out would be correct, i just dont know how to do it and its not described either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I resolved it using javascript SPServices library on codeplex. Here you have link with description how to use it:

http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns

It is quite easy and fast solution you don't have be very familiar with javascript.

If you want to use C# code for it you probably have to create SharePoint custom field type.